# How to change the form icons in apex oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

After the upgrade to ORACLE APEX 18.1, i am getting default select list field stretching up to the entire region instead of just wrapping it up according to the content. Is there a way to switch back to those icons or use something else?[image]

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by select list *icons*?  Can you share a screen shot?

Comment: @JoelR.Kallman, please have a look again. It's more of a form field than an icon. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Universal Theme in APEX 18.1, the default label template is now floating (e.g., "Optional - Floating").  This will always stretch the item to the width of the region.  If you don't want the items to stretch, simply change the label template to something other than floating.